# Mapping/Joining Not Working - Mongoosastic/Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, nodes, mongoosastic

Enviroment

- mongoosastic version: 4.4.1
- node version: 7.10.1
- mongoose version: 4.11.7
- elasticsearch version: 6.4.0

Expectation:

Post Model:
{ usernames : ["5ae2cf1dd18f412bcf522750", "5abc7852f28e0b50530af785", "5b582c6b9751c9672f77324d"] }

Usermodel :
[{_id : 5ae2cf1dd18f412bcf522750, username : "temp"}]

Need to join/map user in post
If a user search the name 'temp' respective post_id should be getting searched by elasticsearch

Actual Behaviour:
Currently unable to map/join

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why this is related with elasticsearch?